# google omniauth rails with devise authentication failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I want add omniauth with Google on my Rails app but i have error after redirection

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, redirect_uri_mismatch: Bad Request
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I saw errors about bad redirection uri but not "bad request"

My redirection uri in google console

```
http://localhost:3000/clients/auth/google_oauth2/callback
```

My route

```
devise_for :clients, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'clients/omniauth_callbacks' }
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem "omniauth-linkedin-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection', '~> 1.0'
```

devise

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], access_type: "online"
```

my link

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Google", client_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your google developer account where you created the credentials. there should be a field named redirect URL where you should place the correct URL. This URL was used to redirect the user from modal opened on login with google.

Comment: I already add my redirect url in credidentials